# "A comment is in place"

Tags: collocation, loanwords

Does the following collocation exist in English?

> a comment is in place

If not, do you recognize it as an improper loan from another language? It is used by a writer to communicate that, before continuing with the normal flow of the text, they feel the need to make a comment on some related topic.

A Google search with this expression returns only 152 results, mostly from academic literature. It seems to be used by a literate population. However, the few number of results in the search and the inferred writers' nationalities make me think this is not an expression a native speaker would use.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you're trying to say that it is *appropriate* to make a comment, not that the comment has been put somewhere (such as in the source code of a computer program).

In that context, it's more common to say that something is *in order*.

> **in order** *phrase*
>   3.1 Appropriate in the circumstances.
>   ‘Maybe some professional expert opinions are in order here.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/in_order)

Comment: "a comment is in order" is much more common: 5110 results on Google.